# Exception on notifyDataSetChanged even using runonuihread

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I have a list view which is populated asynchronously from http responses

Even using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and `calling runOnUiThread`, I am still getting this exception

```
07-21 16:20:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(2003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 16:20:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(2003): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034172, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.ArrayAdapter)]
```

The code I am using is,

```
onRandomAddEventFromRemoteEnd(){
    if (!deviceNames.contains(name)) {
        deviceNames.add(name);
        runOnUiThread(notifyAdapterDataChanged);
    }
}
```

where `deviceNames` is a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and `notifyAdapterDataChanged` is the Runnable

```
Runnable notifyAdapterDataChanged = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            dummyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
```

Comment: Are you running it in a UI thread?

Comment: @user3764893, Yes, my callback `onRandomAddEventFromRemoteEnd` is called by an anonymous thread and i am calling `runOnUiThread`

Comment: Try to call "dummyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" after ending "if block".

Comment: Show the code for whatever is actually downloading the data. What is it? A `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`...something else?

Comment: It's an POSIX thread, running behind JNI

Answer (score 0):

Your error

```
Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread
```

is telling that somehow you might be wrongly modifying your UI.

I would suggest instead calling `runOnUiThread(notifyAdapterDataChanged);` you'd better call a function `runThread()` and change UI there as:

```
 void  runThread(){
         myThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override 
                        public void run() {
                        //Change ui here
                            dummyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
        };
        myThread.start();
     }
```

Comment: I am not sure about that, but it is mostly prefered method to update UI

Comment: I don't think o, Hmm,, However, i just copied your code and called it, Still same crash at same point!!